Defining boundaries of Jewish Orthodoxy
With a plethora of Jewish denominations, it becomes harder and harder to sort out religious views in general and Orthodox Judaism in particular. In my debates, I was frequently pointed out that "a particular view is "not Orthodox", and that caused me to ponder about a method, an algorithm for concluding whether a particular view can be seen as orthodox.
My difficulty in finding one is the fact that the adoption and letting go of ideas in traditional Rabbinic/Talmudic Judaism seems arbitrary and accidental, largely depending on the characters and circumstances involved, not the essence of the ideas themselves.
For example, monogamy was considered "Orthodox" in Christian Europe, while polygamy was "Orthodox" in the Islamic world. Or, if not the charismatic personalities of Chassidic leaders the early Hassidism could be completely ousted like Sabbatarianism (following HaGoen's ban). Or the contemporary ban by the Israeli Ultra-orthodoxy on Rabbi Adin Steinsaltz.
I considered Rambam's 13 principles as some kind of basic consensus, but it becomes somewhat useless if any principle can be interpreted metaphorically, rather than literally. E.g. the principle says "וְאֵין לוֹ שׁוּם דִּמְיוֹן כְּלָל" but our liturgy appeals to God allegorically as "אבינו מלכנו".
Did rabbis or researchers try to systematize the curent-day "orthodox approach" possibly providing hints on methodology?
Note: the question doesn't ask whether a particular idea of view can be considered Orthodox or not.

Cf. The Limits of Orthodox Theology:  Maimonides’ Thirteen Principles Reappraised by Marc B. Shapiro

@J.W.Tanner Thank you, downloaded, and read. Indeed, he analyzes the 13 principles and concludes: "Simply by looking at traditional Jewish
sources, I believe it has been clearly demonstrated that many of his
Principles were not regarded as authoritative, either before his time or
afterwards. The fact that Maimonides placed the stamp of apostasy on
anyone who disagreed with his Principles did not frighten away numerous
great sages from their search for truth. The lesson for moderns is clear."

The principle of "וְאֵין לוֹ שׁוּם דִּמְיוֹן כְּלָל"  is interpreted literally; the prayers are interpreted allegorically.

I think it is damaging to spend to much time o what the limits of Orthodox Judaism are. You end up with a religion focuses on the things we believe in or do that they don't. Instead of one that focuses on the things oue sages said were most I postant. For example, Hillel and Rabbi Aqiva have famous quotes saying that the interpersonal is the central feature of Judaism. But the other movements say that to. So... In 100 years we went from the pursuit of ehrlachkeit to being frum. Because ritual law is where we really have contrast.

That said, there is a hapachic need for a Beis Din to decide whether a conversion candidate accepted Torah uMitzvos or not. And the question will come up on a halachic level on issues like who can be counted toward a minyan or who can handle your uncooked wine. As I see it, it is a halchic issue, not a historian's. If other halachic positions once existed, it doesn't really matter if we hold like some loosened version of the Rambam. And like any other halachic question, expect the gray area of unresolved disputes (machloqes haposqim).

The problem with this question is Orthodox is a popular term without clear definitions; anyone can claim it. What most people care about is halachic Judaism, or pure Judaism without corruptions from non-Jewish influences.

Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/131791/31534. This question would be improved if it were boiled down to the first paragraph - basically "why do people keep telling me my view is non-Orthodox, e.g. view x and view y". The rest is going to cause lots of distracted answers trying to answer your claims about what you think orthodox is. This question could be viewed as "more of a rant in disguise": https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

https://youtu.be/5DlTexEXxLQ?feature=shared

You may need to define Orthodox vs. orthodox. The first is the colloquial term for Torah Judaism, the latter a term to describe something as doctrinally normal ("correct doctrine")

I know of no higher authority on "What is Judaism?" than the consensus of rabbinic opinion over time.  Of course, by "rabbinic opinion," I do not mean "anyone that calls himself or herself a rabbi, without regard to what they believe or say or do," but those men that, having immersed themselves for many years in study of Torah and avodas Hashem, and who are acknowledged by their contemporaries as being among the heirs of previous generations of rabbinic authority.
Which means that I cannot give you any algorithm, any semi-simple series of steps which a computer could walk through to determine "Does this idea fit into Judaism or not?"  The only way to determine that is to become oneself a rabbinic figure of stature, or to ask such a one.
Incidentally, I don't believe that anyone ever claimed that monogamy is a necessary part of Judaism.  That would be a hard thing to do, as two of the Patriarchs had multiple wives simultaneously, as well as various great figures after the Giving of the Torah, most notably Kings David and Solomon!
But monogamy, which even in Biblical times was preferred, has certainly become a very strongly-entrenched custom amongst Ashkenazi and Sephardi Jews, and I would be extraordinarily surprised if polygamy ever returned.

Thank you. Ever heard of "everybody is anybody else's weirdo"? Asking rabbis is not a good method, as we saw with the examples I provided. Now, welcome to MiYodea. Unlike Reddit, here we try to provide knowledgeable answers with sources. Can you spice your answer up with some citations maybe?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for your first answers. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

@AlBerko Sometimes it does have to be a consensus of rabbis across several generations. You mention Chassidus, for example; the Vilna Gaon opposed them strongly, but already the leaders of the next generation (including his star disciple R. Chaim of Volozhin) recognized that it is a legitimate stream of Judaism, and that further disputes with them should take place in the scholarly arena (as in his Nefesh Hachaim). Sabbatarianism, by contrast, was rejected pretty roundly in its own time, and continued to be so afterwards; same with Reform, etc.

@Meir I think you nailed it, basically we wait and see what sticks. The Tannoyim Kosherize (Orthodoxize) the scripture a couple of centuries later, the Talmud does the same to the Mishna and the oral tradition also a couple of centuries later, and so do Geonim, Rishonim, Achronim, etc. We need to wait and see where the wind blows.
